# InvalidAuthenticityToken in Devise::SessionsController#destroy (sign out after already having signed out)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, devise, csrf

I am using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) `3.2.0` for authentication and found an issue when I do the following:

- tab 1: sign **in** to app
- tab 2: go to any page in the app
- tab 2: sign **out** (success)
- tab 1: sign **out** (failure - see exception below)

Exception raised:

> ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in Devise::SessionsController#destroy

In the development log I see:

> Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

And the top three lines of the stack trace are:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:163:in `handle_unverified_request'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:170:in `handle_unverified_request'
  devise (3.2.0) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:198:in `handle_unverified_request'
```

How can I ensure successive *sign outs* don't raise an exception?

Comment: Its not successive sign out, you are trying to sign out, when you are already sign out. so why not sign out user from tab1 , when you sign out from tab2

Comment: I am not sure why you say that this is *not* a successive sign out. *Successive* means *following one another*. If I attempt to sign out in one tab after signing out in another, that is successive as far as I am concerned. The point though is that this is a very reasonable action that users can take. Just one example is that a user opens multiple tabs on a single site, and when they sign out in one tab, and then proceed to successively close the other tabs, they may try to sign out again (due to the signed-in appearance of all other tabs).

Comment: @user664833 now I get it. Yes, Devise should have handled the logout scenario without throwing nasty error. But again, they may say that's what we call `customization`. KirtiThorat's workaround is probably a better solution until Devise implements it.

Comment: See the issue submitted by @freddyrangel https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2934 on Devise Github Repo. You can join the discussion by supporting the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was fixed in `devise 3.3.0`.

- see the [change log for 3.3.0](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#330---2014-08-13)
- see the [file changes in pull request #2968](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/2968/files)
- note `already_signed_out` in `config/locales/en.yml`

Answer (score 13):

Here is whats happening,

When you initially signed out from tab 2, session and authenticity_token associated with the logged in user was destroyed. 
When you try to sign out from tab 1, Devise again tries to destroy the session using the authenticity_token which was destroyed on tab 2.

Hence, you get the error `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` as devise fails to authenticate using the given `authenticity_token`.

You only get one unique session per sign in, if that gets destroyed you'll have nothing to destroy again.

**EDIT**

This behavior is not provided by Devise. If you wish to implement such behavior you will have to override SessionsController.

Create a `sessions_controller.rb` file in `app/controllers/users` directory

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  prepend_before_filter :verify_user, only: [:destroy]

  private
  ## This method intercepts SessionsController#destroy action 
  ## If a signed in user tries to sign out, it allows the user to sign out 
  ## If a signed out user tries to sign out again, it redirects them to sign in page
  def verify_user
    ## redirect to appropriate path
    redirect_to new_user_session_path, notice: 'You have already signed out. Please sign in again.' and return unless user_signed_in?
  end
end
```

Update `routes.rb`

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "users/sessions" }
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand *why* this is happening, but I would like to know *how to make it work without raising an exception*. For example, if you do the same thing on Twitter, or practically any other site, all successive log out attempts are successful - insofar as *not* raising an exception, and making the user believe that they have just signed out (regardless of the fact that *they were actually already signed out*).

Comment: @KirtiThorat I think it would be better if the user gets a flash message e.g. "You have already signed out please login again" and then redirect to login page instead of root_path.

Comment: @user3317140 +1 That sounds like a good idea. Added it to the code.

Comment: @KirtiThorat Looks good. You (or @freddyrangel) should submit a pull request for this workaround to Devise.

Answer (score 7):

A simple solution to this problem could also be allowing sign outs via GET rather than DELETE. In devise.rb you can simply change to:

```
# The default HTTP method used to sign out a resource. Default is :delete.
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

Comment: @CodeWalrus, according to the latest commit it doesn't seem like anything changed for the initializer file. Are you sure this isn't a result of a different issue? https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/868d3d82a014509167ccd7dd3e794171011bffe1/lib/generators/templates/devise.rb#L240

Answer (score 7):

paste this in the layout:
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

Answer (score 3):

If you are still having this issue as i did in `Rails 5` and `devise 4.4.1`, in the app/controllers/application_controller.rb change

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

to

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can change strategy of verify csrf token.

In rails 3 the default strategy when verify is failed, is return a null session. In rails 4 was changed the strategy in application_controller to return a exception.

I solve this, changing in my **application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
-    protect_from_forgery, with: :exception
+    protect_from_forgery
```

This way, use the default strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Kirti is exactly right. I've had this problem yesterday but with a custom authentication solution. If this is really a problem that you want to fix, you could figure out how to override Devise's signout action and add `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` for that action.

Comment: Yes, I realize that I could override Devise's signout action, but I am surprised this is not already correctly handled by Devise, as it is not an uncommon user behaviour. It is surprising to me that Devise would leave this loose end for the developer to fix. How is this behaviour desirable in *any* way?

Comment: You make a good point. I might actually submit a pull request actually.

Comment: Thank you - please do. I.e. if the user is *already* signed out, then bypass the usual code and make it seem as though the user is now signed out.

Comment: @freddyrangel if you have a workaround for this then please do submit a pull request. This default undesirable behavior must go away

Comment: I've submitted an issue on github to see if it's been addressed before. I have the sense that the Devise peeps are really big on security so they might not be keep trying something that may or may not compromise security.

Comment: Weird that the Devise peeps would be really big on security ;) The reason they do it is so that hackers can't log out other people remotely.