# Devise Logout Error in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

While using devise in ROR, I am encountering a strange error when I am trying to log out from an URL that was different from the root URL. It displays me this :

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in Devise::SessionsController#destroy"
```

For example if my rooting path after log in is '/structure', and I try to log out from '/general' I get this error, while logging out from '/structure' is fine.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487290/invalidauthenticitytoken-in-devisesessionscontrollerdestroy-sign-out-after-a