# Testing behavior of post request for non-logged in user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm working on a project where users login and out, a complete shocker I know, and we're ensuring that people can logout when done. One thing we've noticed is that for various reasons a user can try to click the logout button when the system have already logged them out. (Session timeout, logged in from another browser, or other reasons. The site only allows for one concurrent login per user.)

So what happens when the user tries to POST to the logout URL is that they fail a CSRF validation, since they don't have a valid session. We can't remove the CSRF validation because of security concerns.

As such I'm trying to add a test that allows me to test this behavior and so that instead of blowing up with an invalid CSRF token it'll silently accept that the user is already logged out and continue on with its business.

What I've tried is basically this:

```
context 'user is not logged in' do
  before do
    Rails.application.config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = true
  end

  it 'does not blow up' do
    expect { post :destroy, {}, { some_key: 'val' } }.not_to raise_error
  end

  it 'redirects to logout path' do
    expect(response).to redirect_to(successful_logout_path)
  end
end
```

Which goes green despite not having had any logic changes in my controller, and manual testing confirms it's still not working.

Any suggestion for how to enable the CSRF validation for this context, or another way of testing this in the unit tests?

Answer (score 0):

Devise was having a similar problem up until last year. I submitted an issue on Github here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2934  and it was eventually fixed. This other question should give you a hand: [InvalidAuthenticityToken in Devise::SessionsController#destroy (sign out after already having signed out)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487290/invalidauthenticitytoken-in-devisesessionscontrollerdestroy-sign-out-after-a)